# Angular JS 24hr time Input Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I using HTML5 with AngularJS,i have an input field where i am allowing users to enter the time in 24 hour format  eg:(13:00) . when the user clicks on submit button i need to validate whether the input is entered in the above format . If not i would like to throw an error message saying its invalid time . The problem is when i try to do it using normal javascript on ng-click its not working . please suggest me a good way of doing it . How should i do i angular way .

this is my javascript code

```
    function validateTime(obj)
{
var timeValue = obj.value;
if(timeValue == "" || timeValue.indexOf(":")<0)
{
    alert("Invalid Time format");
    return false;
}
else
{
    var sHours = timeValue.split(':')[0];
    var sMinutes = timeValue.split(':')[1];

    if(sHours == "" || isNaN(sHours) || parseInt(sHours)>23)
    {
        alert("Invalid Time format");
        return false;
    }
    else if(parseInt(sHours) == 0)
        sHours = "00";
    else if (sHours <10)
        sHours = "0"+sHours;

    if(sMinutes == "" || isNaN(sMinutes) || parseInt(sMinutes)>59)
    {
        alert("Invalid Time format");
        return false;
    }
    else if(parseInt(sMinutes) == 0)
        sMinutes = "00";
    else if (sMinutes <10)
        sMinutes = "0"+sMinutes;    

    obj.value = sHours + ":" + sMinutes;        
}

return true;    
}
```